# PyCharm interface is blinking

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pycharm

The whole PyCharm window is starting to 'blink' at any moment, even if I do nothing.

I expected I've installed the wrong file (Intel version instead of Apple Silicon), so I reinstalled PyCharm, but it wasn't helpful.
macOS Ventura, Apple Silicon, PyCharm 2022.3

Answer (score 4):

I suffered the exact same problem last year in Pycharm and Datagrip where they would suddenly start flashing like this (marked as a spoiler as it contains a flashing image):

> [image]

The solution I eventually got from JetBrains was to disable Metal rendering. To do this:

- go to `Help | Edit custom VM options...`
- add the line `-Dsun.java2d.metal=false` at the end of the options file, save and restart.

This cured the problem for me instantly.

Reference on YouTrack [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-4680/idea-window-flickers-while-changing-the-screen-brightness#focus=Comments-27-6253379.0-0).